# How to Set Titles and Page Number in Landscape orientation of Crytal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

How to Set Page Number in Landscape orientation of Crytal Report ?

Only appears the titles on the first part.

Thx.

Update : First Picture Report Without Configuration
         Second One Report With Rigth Configuration

```
     Thx KuKeC !!! :)
```

[image: Report Without Configuration]

[image: Report With Right Configuration]

Comment: Didnt get you....can you post picture

Comment: You have a `cross-tab` in your report and when your `cross-tab`doesn't fit into one page (A4 format) then your **right-part** of  `cross-tab` (the part of cross-tab which doesn't fit into 1 A4 page) is printed on page after which should be the same page. It's only on page after because he is too big. If you don't get it, feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: KuKeC -  For me this its a Crystal Report Bug.

Comment: Its kind of both. A CR bug and a design error too. The cross tab is extending way beyond the page size which is why its stretching the page, but mind you technically its still the same page and not a different page and hence one title and one page number. I am not familiar with cross tabs, but you could use something like "keep together" function (if available)

Comment: @RicardoBalda You can't tell that something is a bug just because it doesn't work your way. You asked a question and you've got several comments about why is this happening to you. So start to figure out how to ask for help rather than accepting your problem as a bug.

Comment: KuKeC - It is not my way, it is common sense, if CR automatically set page brake Why don't fill the titles ? :)

Comment: @RicardoBalda It is your way because CR does what you told him to do. In your case he did  not show you elements on situation when you have several horizontal pages. When you turn that option on then you got your problem solved. He don't fill the titles because his "default" settings doesn't tell him to do that. Frustrating situations make us believe that the tool (CR) is full of bugs but it's happening only because of lack of knowledge about it. There are some situations which can't be solved, but when that happens CR will have improve with new functionalities etc from developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion i made myself example with cross-tab with the same problem and i figure out solution. So as you can read in my comments above, it's not about CR bug, it's about users don't know all the functionality of CR.

So to make this work, **select all your fields in report header** (titles, boxes etc.) and `right click` on them and click `format field`. After that check option `Repeat on Horizontal Page` and it should do it (selected red on image).

[image]

If you have any more question feel free to ask

Hope it helps

Comment: Kukec - You are rigth, but page number dont increment, this is a minor issue but user may ask to increment the page number to avoid confussion. Thx a lot.